# What should I learn from heterodox economy?

Tags: general-equilibrium

As a graduate and master student, everything I've learned and I'm learning is from mainstream economy which in some parts seems like propaganda. Most of theories comes from the hypotesis of perfect compentence and other not general proved statements with a mathematical logic, that is clean, however if the premises aren't true, the conclusion don't hold.

Therefore I would like to open my mind and learn from other sources.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi welcome to economics stack exchange. Please note this is not a discussion forum but an Q&A site. Open ended, chatty, too broad and opinion based questions are of topic here. You should feel free to post questions about heterodox economics but the questions should still follow our rules (see help center for details). For example, what area of research are you even talking about? What research did you do before posting on this site? Are you looking for book request, video request note request? You should keep your question narrow. As it is the question breaks too many rules so it is closed

Comment: But feel free to revise it in accordance with our rules and it could be reopened later

Comment: I will try my best next time